# Edit shapes in java3d

Tags: java, swing, 3d, java-3d

I want to know if it is possible to edit a shape (for e.g. Cube) in runtime?
Like I have a Cube drawn and i have to edit it in runtime, for e.g. change the height, width or depth of the cube.

Please let me know if such a thing is possible

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's commonly possible. Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Just make a few extra methods pertaining to Java-3D that allow you to manipulate the shape, first of all, and then depending on which shape you could have a resize() method overridden where you get which shape it is and use polymorphism to tell which shape it is. Use an item from the toolbox to adjust size.